# How to use Apple Pay by Stripe

Tags: ios, payment, stripe-payments

I try to work Apple Pay by Stripe, but it has some issue.
This is my code:

```
- (void)hasToken:(STPToken *)token {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *chargeParams = @{
        @"token": token.tokenId,
        @"currency": @"usd",
        @"amount": @"1000", // this is in cents (i.e. $10)
    };
    NSLog(@"Token ID: %@", token.tokenId);
    if (!ParseApplicationId || !ParseClientKey) {
        UIAlertView *message =
            [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Todo: Submit this token to your backend"
                                       message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Good news! Stripe turned your credit card into a token: %@ \nYou can follow the "
                                                                          @"instructions in the README to set up Parse as an example backend, or use this "
                                                                          @"token to manually create charges at dashboard.stripe.com .",
                                                                          token.tokenId]
                                      delegate:nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [message show];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        return;
    }

    // This passes the token off to our payment backend, which will then actually complete charging the card using your account's
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"charge"
                       withParameters:chargeParams
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                                    if (error) {
                                        [self hasError:error];
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                                                      completion:^{
                                                                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Payment Succeeded"
                                                                                                                      message:nil
                                                                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                                                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                                                                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];
                                                                                      }];
                                }];
}
```

After input number card, then "Pay" button click, and then jump to function:

```
// This passes the token off to our payment backend, which will then actually complete charging the card using your account's
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"charge"
                       withParameters:chargeParams
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                                    if (error) {
                                        [self hasError:error];
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                                                      completion:^{
                                                                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Payment Succeeded"
                                                                                                                      message:nil
                                                                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                                                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                                                                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];
                                                                                      }];
                                }];
```

But it's jump to function:

```
- (void)hasError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
                                                      message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}
```

And show error message:
    Error: function not found (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.20)

Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 parts to your question.  Firstly, it seems that you might have already reached the point in your code where you have an STPtoken and you just have to be able to run a charge with it.  It looks like there is an error with your cloud code.  You will want to make sure you have a function called "charge" or else it will return the error.  You could do something like the following (in javascript) to create a customer and create the charge:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("charge", function(request, response) {
  Stripe.Customers.create({
    card: request.params.token,
    description: request.params.description
  },{
    success: function(results) {
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      response.error(httpResponse);
    }
  }).then(function(customer){
    return Stripe.Charges.create({
      amount: request.params.amount, // in cents
      currency: request.params.currency,
      customer: customer.id
    },{
    success: function(results) {
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      response.error(httpResponse);
    }
  });
 });
});
```

Then the second part of your question has to do with working with Apple Pay.  With apple pay, you can create a token without ever asking for the user for their payment info.  In order to implement Apple Pay, you need the following code:

```
#import <PassKit/PassKit.h>
#import "Stripe.h" //Necessary as ApplePay category might be ignored if the preprocessor macro conditions are not met
#import "Stripe+ApplePay.h"

PKPaymentRequest *request = [Stripe
                             paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:APPLE_MERCHANT_ID];
NSString *label = @"Text"; //This text will be displayed in the Apple Pay authentication view after the word "Pay"
NSDecimalNumber *amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.00"]; //Can change to any amount
request.paymentSummaryItems = @[
                                [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:label
                                                                    amount:amount]
                                ];

if ([Stripe canSubmitPaymentRequest:request]) {
    PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *auth = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
    auth.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:auth animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This code creates a payment, tests to see if the payment could potentially be processed, and if so, displays the payment authorization view.  I place this code in `viewDidAppear` in the view controller that contains the ability to collect the user's payment info.  If the payment is able to be processed, then the payment authorization view controller will appear over the current view controller, allowing the user to decide if they want to enter in the payment info themselves or use apple pay.  Make sure to declare that the current view controller adheres to the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate.  And in `viewDidLoad` make sure to set the delegate.

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                       didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion {
    [self handlePaymentAuthorizationWithPayment:payment completion:completion];
}
```

This will be called if the user decides to use their fingerprint and use Apple Pay

```
- (void)handlePaymentAuthorizationWithPayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                   completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion {
    [Stripe createTokenWithPayment:payment
                        completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
                            if (error) {
                                completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
                                return;
                            }
                            //USE TOKEN HERE
                        }];
}
```

This will be called to process the payment.  It will create the token you require to process the payment.  The rest of your code can be used with this token.

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This will be called after the payment has been processed.  The payment authorization view controller will be dismissed.